# Fastest way to open list of videos Thumbnails

Tags: android, mediastore, video-thumbnails

I would like to know what is the fastest way to read Thumbnail of a video?

My problem is that I've had a couple of videos files and I need to get the thumbnail from all of them.

For now I'm using :

```
thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(FullPath,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
```

This is working good if I have only one video, but if I have even 6 videos it can take a 3 seconds to read all of the thumbnail .

Is someone know another way to read thumbnails that is faster than this mechanism?

Thanks

Comment: You could try to do async tasks for them and do it simultaneously.

Comment: I tried to do that, but it takes also too long to open the activity. maybe I do it wrong, may you give me an example please?

Comment: what does **Fastest** means to you ?

Comment: If i need to wait 3 sec for 6 files this is a lot of time. I want to know if there a way to load them faster than this.

Comment: Btw, when you load the images, what's the quality of the images? Scaling them and setting down the quality is also something you could look into.

Comment: I don't know what is the quality, I just knoe that I take the smaller image. You can see the code bellow, this is exactly what I do.

Answer (score 0):

do like this

```
    ImageView thumbnail_mini = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_mini);
    ImageView thumbnail_micro = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_micro);

    Bitmap bmThumbnail;

    // MICRO_KIND: 96 x 96 thumbnail
    bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath, 
   Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
    thumbnail_micro.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);

    // MINI_KIND: 512 x 384 thumbnail 
    bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath, 
   Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
    thumbnail_mini.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);
```

Comment: This is exactly what i did.I'm using only the MICRO kind but it takes me too long